# Почему не модифицируются сессии между разными php скриптами?

Tags: php

У меня есть несколько по сути изолированных друг от друга скрипта, то есть каждый раз запускается какой-то из них при запросе, родителя как такового нет. Вот я делаю запрос на `login.php`, проверяю данные и записываю сессию:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['role'] = 2;
```

Затем в другой скрипте, `getProducts.php`, я валидирую права доступа по значению в сессии

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['role'] !== 2) {
  http_response_code(403);
  exit();
}
else {
  $resp['role'] = $_SESSION['role'];
  http_response_code(200);
  echo json_encode($resp);
  exit();
}
```

В примере выше я просто возвращаю роль, чтобы из консоли наблюдать за ее состоянием. И в этой ситуации роль равняется "2" - скрипт работает, все ок, права доступа валидируются.
Сейчас я хочу удалить сессии пользователя, по сути разлогинить его, чтобы протестировать, что скрипты не будут пускать человека без сессии. Я создал `logout.php` и поместил в него разные вариации кода:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION);
echo json_encode(['role' => $_SESSION['role'], 'id' => $_SESSION['id']]);
```

.

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['role']);
echo json_encode(['role' => $_SESSION['role'], 'id' => $_SESSION['id']]);
```

.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
echo json_encode(['role' => $_SESSION['role'], 'id' => $_SESSION['id']]);
```

.

```
<?php
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_abort();

echo json_encode(['role' => $_SESSION['role'], 'id' => $_SESSION['id']]);
```

и даже

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['role'] = 'dfdfdfdf';
echo json_encode(['role' => $_SESSION['role'], 'id' => $_SESSION['id']]);
```

и т.д.

В ответе на запрос к `logout.php` я вижу, что `$_SESSION['role'] === null`

Но затем, когда я снова делаю запрос к `getProducts.php` я снова получаю в ответе role = 2.

Почему сохранение сессий между отдельными скриптами работает (в файле `login.php`) работает и переменная читается в других скриптах (`getProducts.php`), но их дальнейшая модификация в других файлах (`$_SESSION['role'] = 'dfdfdfdf';`) не меняет значение для всех остальных скриптов? Как очистить сессии в одном скрипте для остальных?

Comment: вы уверены что вы с одной и той же сессией оперируете? `session_id()` во всех скриптах один? (или кука PHPSESSID у запросов)

Comment: Вы не забываете сбрасывать кэш браузера между запросами?

Comment: @andreymal забываю

Comment: @andreymal но это ни на что не повлияло((

Comment: @teran действительно разные id. Можно сетить через session_id(newId) - но как мне тогда между скриптами ее передать? В мануалах что нашел таким не заморачиваются почему-то.

Comment: Может быть, сессионная кука устанавливается только для текущей страницы, а не для всего сайта, проверьте path в куке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885487

Comment: @andreymal почему-то не помогло( все равно разные id, хммм

Comment: @andreymal более того, в php.ini и так стоит session.cookie_path = /